# Trigger rerender after setTimeout in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timeout

I am trying to get my head around React, and I am doing some projects. One of them involving rerendering a component after a variable changes after setTime out runs out.

I am supposing it has to rerender, since it changes after the initial render ( and that it doesn't react (heh) the the updated variable.

I am guessing I am misunderstanding some React fundamentals here.

Arrows to highligt my problem.

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Navigation.module.css';

const navigation = (props) => {
    let attachedClasses = [classes.SmallDot];
    let showCloseButton = false; <-------!
    if (props.currentState) {
        attachedClasses = [classes.BigDot]
        setTimeout(() => {
            showCloseButton = true; <----------!
        }, 500)

    }

    return (
        <div onClick={props.currentState ? null : props.toggleMenuState} className={attachedClasses.join(' ')}>
            {showCloseButton ? <--------!
                <div onClick={props.toggleMenuState} className={classes.CloseButton}>
                    <div>X</div>
                </div>
                : null}
        </div>
    )
};

export default navigation;
```

Comment: Regular variables defined with `let/const` won't trigger re-renders when changed. Re-renders are triggered by changes in props or state. So put the `showCloseButton` in a state hook (`useState`) and then update it's value with the function returned from it. There's lots of docs/examples out there on state hooks, quick Google search should find plenty

Comment: That worked absolutely perfectly, thank you! I am wondering though, and I don't know if comments is the right place to discuss this. I've learned the convention for class based states should be handled in few locations. I already have a useState in my App component, but is it fine to use useState in whatever component you would like, or would it be better to localize it?

Comment: State in functional and class components is exactly the same. They're declared differently, but they're functionality identical, so you can `useState` in whatever component you like, whichever one needs local state